# Error: unused arguments in ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement, arguments, dplyr, discretization

I tried to discretise a column in dataframe df using ifelse statements using the following code. The column aar contains decimal values from 0 to 12 and NAs. I check if the numeric value and assign it to the categories as below.

```
> df= df%>% mutate(arr2= ifelse( grepl("NA", aar)==T, "NA",
> ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==0, "0-0.99", ifelse(as.numeric(aar))==1,
> "1-1.99", ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==2, "2-2.99",
> ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==3, "3-3.99", ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==4,
> "4-4.99", ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==5, "5-5.99",
> ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==6, "6-6.99", ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==7,
> "7-7.99", ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==8,
> "8-8.99",ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==9, "9-9.99",
> ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==10, "10-10.99",  ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==11,
> "11-11.99", "12" )))))))))))))
```

But I get the following error,

```
Error: unused arguments ("1-1.99", ifelse(as.numeric(c("0", "NA", "0",......
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone kindly help me to fix this please?

Comment: Use `cut()` or `factor()` instead.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are prematurely closing a parenthesis in your *second* call to `ifelse`:

```
> ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==0, "0-0.99", ifelse(as.numeric(aar))==1,
```

should be:

```
> ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==0, "0-0.99", ifelse(as.numeric(aar)==1,
```

I'm not an R guru like @akrun, but there must be a better way to achieve what you are trying to do, instead of nesting 12 `ifelse` calls.  Your current approach makes the code hard to read, and harder to debug (hence your question).